# Question Mark Appears after login then disapears

Tags: 16.04

Everytime when I login in ubuntu 16.04.1, two question mark icons appear in the left bar of the desktop, then, some seconds after, they disappear. What could I do to avoid this?

After running the command systemd-analyze blame, it is shown in the output:

```
380ms dev-sda5.device
265ms alsa-restore.service
247ms systemd-timesyncd.service
137ms snapd.firstboot.service
132ms apparmor.service
125ms ModemManager.service
117ms accounts-daemon.service
114ms systemd-modules-load.service
111ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-A021\x2dDF65.service
 88ms systemd-localed.service
 88ms systemd-hostnamed.service
 83ms systemd-logind.service
 82ms grub-common.service
 69ms NetworkManager.service
 69ms keyboard-setup.service
 67ms systemd-journald.service
 64ms plymouth-start.service
 62ms speech-dispatcher.service
 61ms systemd-udevd.service
 54ms ondemand.service
 53ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
 49ms thermald.service
 48ms console-setup.service
 47ms apport.service
 45ms irqbalance.service
 43ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-50516ce7\x2d3a77\x2d44fd\x2d90bc\x2d2a69ac4acfac.service
 40ms pppd-dns.service
 40ms networking.service
 37ms home.mount
 37ms rsyslog.service
 37ms systemd-user-sessions.service
 37ms gpu-manager.service
 35ms avahi-daemon.service
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/832276/edit) your question with the output of `systemd-analyze blame`.

Comment: Where should I put this?

Comment: In your question. Click on edit from my comment or below your question.

Comment: Ok, I added the output of the command in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Any ideia what is happening?

Comment: Could someone help?

Comment: @Eng_Heisenberg, Could take a picture or screenshot of what you see?